# Absolutely no terminal will open in PhpStorm terminal shell

Tags: phpstorm, git-bash, jetbrains-ide

I have run into a problem where PhpStorm has basically stopped opening any terminals...

When I installed it everything was fine, when I changed the terminal path to bash it stopped working and will not recover now even if i will set it back to default or reinstall.

I have also tried installing an older version of PhpStorm, which is on my other computer where everything is fine, still no luck.

[image: When I open the terminal I see this]

idea.log shows some errors (i am terribly sorry for formatting but i have no idea how should i post it)

> 2018-07-02 10:56:17,607 [   9411]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - PhpStorm 2018.1.6  Build #PS-181.5281.35 
>   2018-07-02 10:56:17,607 [   9411]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - JDK: 1.8.0_152-release 
>   2018-07-02 10:56:17,607 [   9411]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
>   2018-07-02 10:56:17,607 [   9411]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
>   2018-07-02 10:56:17,607 [   9411]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - OS: Windows 10 
>   2018-07-02 10:56:17,607 [   9411]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Last Action:
>   2018-07-02 10:56:17,653 [   9457]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === StatusBar.update create === 
>   2018-07-02 10:56:17,654 [   9458]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === doConnect === 
>   2018-07-02 10:56:17,654 [   9458]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === getConnectionState === 
>   2018-07-02 10:56:17,775 [   9579]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 42ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
>   2018-07-02 10:56:17,816 [   9620]   INFO - .cloudConfig.CloudConfigClient - === Get cloud config URL: https://cloudconfig.jetbrains.com/cloudconfig/files === 
>   2018-07-02 10:56:18,003 [   9807]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 227ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: 0/1 sluggish, 1/1 very slow 
>   2018-07-02 10:56:18,172 [   9976]   INFO - j.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider - 321 ms spent to cache options in application 
>   2018-07-02 10:56:18,188 [   9992]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - C:/Users/Ri?adas Pukelis/PhpstormProjects/untitled/.idea case-sensitivity: expected=false actual=false 
>   2018-07-02 10:56:18,189 [   9993]   INFO - Json.PackageJsonUpdateNotifier - processPackageJsonFiles [] 
>   2018-07-02 10:56:18,210 [  10014]   INFO - pl.projectlevelman.NewMappings - VCS Root: [] - [] 
>   2018-07-02 10:56:18,401 [  10205]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 4187 ms 
>   2018-07-02 10:56:18,441 [  10245]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === StatusBar.start another widget: com.intellij.cloudConfig.StatusBarInfoManager$InfoComponent@52fb6fd3 === 
>   2018-07-02 10:56:18,452 [  10256]   INFO - j.ide.plugins.RepositoryHelper - using cached plugin list (updated at 7/2/18 10:56 AM) 
>   2018-07-02 10:56:18,644 [  10448]   INFO - j.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider - 118 ms spent to cache options in project 
>   2018-07-02 10:56:18,703 [  10507]   INFO - j.ide.plugins.RepositoryHelper - using cached plugin list (updated at 7/2/18 10:56 AM) 
>   2018-07-02 10:56:18,770 [  10574]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === End.connect === 
>   2018-07-02 10:56:29,322 [  21126]   INFO - .script.IdeScriptEngineManager - javax.script.ScriptEngineManager initialized in 44 ms 
>   2018-07-02 10:57:05,039 [  56843]   INFO - ide.actions.ShowFilePathAction - 
>   Exit code 1

Comment: What PhpStorm version is that? Any errors in Help > Show Log in ... > idea.log when you reproduce the problem?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, version 2018.1.6, there are some errors in the log, i will update the question to include it

Comment: Was there any stack trace before the first line? Error text itself doesn't give any clues. Uploading the log to pastebin or similar resource may be an option.